# Adding a Time Condition to an order in Interactive Broker's API

Tags: python, interactive-brokers

Good evening, I need big help and it will be greatly appreciated. I am trying to add a time condition to my order but I don't understand IBKR's API.

This is the sample code they provide:

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.order import *
from threading import Timer
from ibapi.order_condition import OrderCondition, Create

class TestApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)

    def error(self, reqId , errorCode, errorString):
        print("Error: ", reqId, " ", errorCode, " ", errorString)

    def nextValidId(self, orderId ):
        self.nextOrderId = orderId
        self.start()

    def orderStatus(self, orderId , status, filled, remaining, avgFillPrice, permId, parentId, lastFillPrice, clientId, whyHeld, mktCapPrice):
        print("OrderStatus. Id: ", orderId, ", Status: ", status, ", Filled: ", filled, ", Remaining: ", remaining, ", LastFillPrice: ", lastFillPrice)

    def openOrder(self, orderId, contract, order, orderState):
        print("OpenOrder. ID:", orderId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, "@", contract.exchange, ":", order.action, order.orderType, order.totalQuantity, orderState.status)

    def execDetails(self, reqId, contract, execution):
        print("ExecDetails. ", reqId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, contract.currency, execution.execId,
              execution.orderId, execution.shares, execution.lastLiquidity)
    
  

    

    def start(self):
        
        
        contract = Contract()
        contract.symbol = "AAPL"
        contract.secType = "STK"
        contract.exchange = "SMART"
        contract.currency = "USD"
        contract.primaryExchange = "NASDAQ"

        order = Order()
        order.action = "BUY"
        order.totalQuantity = 10
        order.orderType = "MKT"
        
    
        self.placeOrder(self.nextOrderId, contract, order)
        
        



    def stop(self):
        self.done = True
        self.disconnect()

def main():
    app = TestApp()
    app.nextOrderId = 0
    app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, 9)

    Timer(3, app.stop).start()
    app.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The documentation for Order Conditioning is found at:

https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/order_conditions.html

How do I plug the time condition in the above code. Let's say I am buying 100 stocks of AAPL on July 20th 2023 at 2:30pm? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample bit of code that will do what you want. If you pass an order to this function it will add a time based condition and return the order.

```
from ibapi.order_condition import OrderCondition, Create

def add_time_condition(order, start_datetime, orth=True):
    
    time_condition = Create(OrderCondition.Time)
    time_condition.time = datetime.strftime(start_datetime, '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')
    time_condition.isMore = True
    # isMore = True : specified time is the earliest acceptable time
    # isMore = False: specified time is the latest acceptable time
    time_condition.isConjunctionConnection = "AND"  # alternatively "OR"
    
    order.conditions.append(time_condition)
    order.conditionsIgnoreRth = orth

    return order
```

You can see that the basic idea is to create an OrderCondition.Time object, and populate it with the relevant parameters (time, isMore, and isConjunctionConnection if multiple conditions are being added).

You then append that Condition to the conditions parameter of the Order object.  The conditions parameter of the Order object is just a list and you can append multiple Conditions to that list.  If you are adding multiple Conditions you will need to set the isConjunctionConnection parameter of each Condition.

A separate parameter on the Order object is the conditionsIgnoreRth - this tells the API whether the condition(s) should operate in extended trading hours or just regular trading hours.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ran the code with the added suggestion but it executes immediately rather than waiting for specified date. I edited the code with your suggestion. Do you think you can guide me on which part of it is causing this behaviour?

Comment: What datetime did you pass to the function, and what timezone are you in?
Also, in your edited code above, you still need to pass the order to the function before you place the order, like this:

```self.add_time_condition(order, datetime(2023,20,7,14,30,0), orth=True)```

Also, please don't add the solution into your original question - it can be confusing if people look at it in the future.

Comment: I added this line : self.add_time_condition(order, datetime(2023,20,7,14,30,0), orth=True) in the def Start block before and after and now it saying : NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined

Comment: Yes, you'll need to import the datetime library using:
```from datetime import datetime```
That's a fairly basic python thing.  Maybe you could consider some online python and TWS API courses?  Otherwise it can be frustrating for you as you encounter a seemingly endless series of errors/things that don't work.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your input so far. I bought a course for that specific api but there is no lesson in it for placing orders at a specific time. I have added all your suggestions, now I am getting this error: add_time_condition() got multiple values for argument 'orth'

Comment: Have a look at the line you are using to call the add_time_condition() function - there should only be 3 parameters inside the brackets with types as: (order, datetime, boolean)

Comment: Still not working now it says: 'TestApp' object has no attribute 'conditions'

Comment: Ok, you should be able to debug that yourself - it has nothing to do with the the add_time_condition function itself, and instead has to do with where you have put the function in your code, and the type of variable you are passing to it (you appear to be passing the App object to the function instead of an Order object).  
An essential part of programming is developing the skills to understand these errors and backtrace them to find out the cause yourself - SO is not really the forum for that.

Comment: I can't even debug my shoes. HELP!

Comment: Make sure the def add_time_condition function itself is inside the TestApp class (i.e. indented once, sitting with all the other TestApp functions)
Then call it by adding this line directly before your placeorder line above:
```self.add_time_condition(order, '20220724 02:30:00')```
See if that helps